# Django conditional query by matching boolean values

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm, django-filter, django-q

I know there is a few ways this can be achieved, i.e. if/else query sets, conditional query sets, Q, aggregate etc. I have come up with a few options based on these but want to know best approach and suggestions.

Sudo code is below on what I am trying to achieve. App would pass in query string for boolean values as below i.e. either True or False, if one user has more matches based on the query string values and database data they would be ordered higher than other users.

```
SELECT * from userdetails

    if sun_morn is true then match_count++
    if sun_day is true then match_count++
    if sun_afternoon is true then match_count++
    if sun_afternoon is true then match_count++

order_by match_count LIMIT by 10;
```

Result is to show all users that match any one of the booleans then order the user with the most matches at the top of the query set.

With help of @Aison code is, close but not working:

```
    """ /endpoint?sunmorn=1&sunday=0&sunafternoon=0&sunnight=1&monmorn=1&monday=0&monafternoon=0&monnight=1
    &tuesmorn=1&tuesday=0&tuesafternoon=0&tuesnight=1&wedmorn=1&wedday=0&wedafternoon=0&wednight=1
    &thursmorn=1&thursday=0&thursafternoon=0&thursnight=1&frimorn=1&friday=0&friafternoon=0&frinight=1
    &satmorn=1&satday=0&satafternoon=0&satnight=1 """
    queryset = queryset.aggregate(match_count=Sum(
        Case(When(sun_morn | sun_day | sun_afternoon | sun_night,
                  then=1), output_field=IntegerField())
    ),
    )
```

models.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

class userdetail(models.Model):
    username = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    # removed extra fields as not needed for example
    sun_morn = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=False, blank=False)
    sun_day = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=False, blank=False)
    sun_afternoon = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=False, blank=False)
    sun_night = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=False, blank=False)
    mon_morn = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=False, blank=False)
    mon_day = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=False, blank=False)
    mon_afternoon = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=False, blank=False)
    mon_night = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=False, blank=False)
    tues_morn = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=False, blank=False)
    tues_day = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=False, blank=False)
    tues_afternoon = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=False, blank=False)
    tues_night = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=False, blank=False)
    wed_morn = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=False, blank=False)
    wed_day = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=False, blank=False)
    wed_afternoon = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=False, blank=False)
    wed_night = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=False, blank=False)
    thurs_morn = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=False, blank=False)
    thurs_day = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=False, blank=False)
    thurs_afternoon = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=False, blank=False)
    thurs_night = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=False, blank=False)
    fri_morn = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=False, blank=False)
    fri_day = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=False, blank=False)
    fri_afternoon = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=False, blank=False)
    fri_night = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=False, blank=False)
    sat_morn = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=False, blank=False)
    sat_day = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=False, blank=False)
    sat_afternoon = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=False, blank=False)
    sat_night = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=False, blank=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.username
```

Comment: and your question?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is  [Conditional aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-aggregation)

```
userdetails.objects.aggregate(
    match_count =Sum(
        Case(When(sun_morn | sun_day | sun_afternoon | sun_afternoon,
            then=1),output_field=IntegerField())
    ),
)
```

#### EDIT

if you store unicode or str in the field, you can use:

```
userdetail.objects.aggregate(
    match_count=Sum(
        Case(
            When(sun_morn=True, then=1),
            When(sun_day=True, then=1), 
            When(sun_afternoon=True, then=1),
            output_field=IntegerField())))
```

OR

```
userdetail.objects.aggregate(
    match_count=Sum(
        Case(When(
            Q(sun_morn=True) | Q(sun_day=True) | 
            Q(sun_afternoon=True), then=1),              
            output_field=IntegerField())))
```

Comment: Thanks Aison that looks right however I am seeing an error:
unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'unicode' and 'unicode'

Comment: Thanks Windsor but I am now seeing error: __init__() takes either a Q object or lookups as keyword arguments

Comment: Thanks Windsooon, now I see error: 'bool' object is not iterable

Comment: If I query to the database fields I also get error: unhashable type
See my MORE EDIT above.

Comment: Please add your model.py

Comment: To confirm what I need is to get boolean values from my query string, then query database for any user that matches the boolean values WHERE true matches, then order the users by the most matches based on the query string values and the database values. Expected result is a list of 10 different users, the one with the most true matches at the top.

Comment: Model added to initial post =)

Comment: I think this is what you want.

Comment: Hmm yes I tried that also and get: ValueError need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: In my first answer, did you use When(sun_morn | sun_day |.... or When("sun_morn" | "sun_day" |...

Comment: I edit my answer, I'm sure both of them will work now.